# PDO Insert multiple checkbox values in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, pdo

I want insert multiple checkbox values in Mysql using PDO.

HTML Form part checkbox

```
<form action="insert.php">
    <label>
        <input name="check[]" id="check[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$row['id']?>" />
        <span class="lbl"></span>
    </label>
    <button type="submit" name="send" id="send" >
</form>
```

PHP Part insert

```
$checkbox = $_POST['check'];

for (i$=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++)

    $insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (check_value) VALUES (?)");
    $insert->execute(array(".$checkbox[$i]."));
```

More when i use ".$checkbox[$i]." give "Notice: Array to string conversion"

Comment: There's only one checkbox there. Could you post the whole code, maybe including the `php` part? I believe this is supposed to be in a loop coming from a database.

Comment: _“HERE I WANT THE INSTRUCTION FOR INSERT EVERY CHECKBOX VALUE IN A ROW”_ – there is no such thing. Use a loop.

Comment: Beter to move that checkbox out of the label and start using the `for`attribute

Comment: Yeah, in truly the checkbox be inside a table, this could help?

Comment: I try this "for (i$=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++)" and 'code'".$checkbox[$i]."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is build the SQL dynamicaly.
Just add as many `?` to the SQL as there are checkbox values.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['check'])) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO TABLE (check_value) VALUES ({foo})';

    $foo = '';
    foreach($_POST['check'] as $key => $value) $foo .= '?,';
    $foo = rtrim($foo, ',');

    $sql = str_replace('{foo}', $foo, $sql);

    $insert = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $insert->execute($_POST['check']);
}
```